# How to read images with different size in a TFRecord file

Tags: python, deep-learning, tensorflow

I have created a dataset and saved it into a TFRecord file. The thing is the pictures have different size, so I want to save the size as well with the images. So I used the TFRecordWriter and defined the features like:

```
example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
  'rows': _int64_feature(image.shape[0]),
  'cols': _int64_feature(image.shape[1]),
  'image_raw': _bytes_feature(image_raw)}))
```

I expected that I can read and decode the image using TFRecordReader, but the thing is I cannot get the value of rows and cols from the file because they are tensors. So how am I supposed to do to read the size dynamically and reshape the image accordingly. Thanks guys

Answer (score 7):

You can call `tf.reshape` with a dynamic `shape` parameter.

```python
image_rows = tf.cast(features['rows'], tf.int32)
image_cols = tf.cast(features['cols'], tf.int32)
image_data = tf.decode_raw(features['image_raw'], tf.uint8)
image = tf.reshape(image_data, tf.pack([image_rows, image_cols, 3]))
```

Comment: it raised the error "All shapes must be fully defined: 1". from the log, it seems it has something to do with function "tf.train.shuffle_batch()". What am I supposed to do then?

Comment: batch needs to know shapes during graph construction (so that it knows how much memory to allocate for queue), perhaps use tf.image.resize_images before tf.batch? If you use any of the standard convnets, you are going to need to resize images to the same size anyway

Comment: +Tong Shen, since you are constructing a batch, images must have the same size. If you know this size in advance, maybe you can call something like `image.set_shape([32,32,3])` to fully define the shape.

Comment: @Yaroslav Bulatov thx for your comment, but the thing is resizing an image will distort the image because I dont know the ratio. For example, I am using PASCAL dataset for segmentation, where pictures have different ratio and size. I know in the batch the images should have the same size, so I am going to randomly crop the image, like 500*500. So for those whose shorter dimension is less than 500 like 400*500, I am gonna resize it to 500*625 in order to keep the ratio. So I still have to know the size the image when I do the decoding and reshaping thing.

Comment: @bgshi Thx for ur reply. Like I said above, the images have different sizes, this is the problem.

Comment: Tong Shen -- can you move the operations that do cropping/resizing/turning everything into the same size before "batch"?

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov I do have the everything before batch. I wanted to make random crop to make pictures into like 500*500, but before this, I do have to read the data stream from the file and reshape it to an array. since I dont not know the length of the "image string", I could not reshape it to the desired image. The issue is that I cannot decide the size of images in advance because they have different sizes.

Comment: @TongShen I have the same problem. TF has the `tf.image.resize_image_with_crop_or_pad` method, but it needs to know the fixed shape of the image.
It is a bug https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/521

Answer (score 4):

I suggest a workflow like:

```
TARGET_HEIGHT = 500
TARGET_WIDTH = 500

image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_buffer, channels=3)
image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, dtype=tf.float32)

# Choose your bbox here.
bbox_begin = ...  (should be (h_start, w_start, 0))
bbox_size = tf.constant((TARGET_HEIGHT, TARGET_WIDTH, 3), dtype=tf.int32)

cropped_image = tf.slice(image, bbox_begin, bbox_size)
```

`cropped_image` has a constant tensor size, and can then be thrown into a shuffle batch.

You can dynamically access the size of the decoded image using `tf.shape(image)`.  You can do computations on the resulting sub-elements and then stitch them back together using something like `bbox_begin = tf.pack([bbox_h_start, bbox_y_start, 0])`.  Just need to insert your own logic in there for determining the start points of the crop, and what you want to do if the image starts out smaller than you want for your pipeline.

If you want to upsize *only* if the image is smaller than your target dimensions, you'll need to use `tf.control_flow_ops.cond` or equivalent.  But you *could* use min and max operations to set the size of your crop window so that you're returning the full image iff it's smaller than the requested dimensions, and then unconditionally resize up to 500x500.  The cropped image will already be at 500x500, so the resize should become an effective no-op.

Comment: is this workflow going to be working with FIFO file queue? Now the thing is I want to randomly crop the picture using 500*500, your way seems crop a fixed region. Now I have resized the images in advance so the minimum dimension is equal or larger than 500. The only thing I am facing is how to decode the image from raw string and reshape it to its original size. Since the weight and height vary in images, we cannot use a fixed size.

Comment: Right, you need to randomly pick the start of the 500x500 bbox.  By setting the bbox_size to [500, 500, 3]   (the 3 is for the # of channels), you'll get a 500x500 crop.  You have to set the start points for your random crop, depending on your preferred random crop algorithm.  Given that you've resized, you could simply do `imageshape = tf.shape(image)` and then set the start, end points like:  `h_start = tf.random_uniform([], minval=0, maxval=imageshape[0]-500, dtype=tf.int32)` and similarly for w_start.